# Find high and low prices in sql

Tags: t-sql

In this sample database there are two tables, products and prices. 
The goal is to find the highest and the lowest price for each product.

The price table can have either zero, one or two rows per product.

```
create table products(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(50)
)

create table prices(
    productId int,
    price int
)

insert into products (id, name) values (33,'bike')
insert into products (id, name) values (44,'car')
insert into products (id, name) values (55,'bus')

insert into prices (productId, price) values (33, 10)
insert into prices (productId, price) values (33, 40)
insert into prices (productId, price) values (44, 300)
```

The sql query should result in this:

```
productId  highPrice  lowPrice
33         40         10
44         300        NULL
55         NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the table that you're looking for (I notice that the other answers don't), in SQL Server 2005

```
select P.ID as ProductID, 
nullif(sum(case when idx=1 then price else 0 end), 0) as highPrice,
nullif(sum(case when idx=2 then price else 0 end), 0) as lowPrice  from
(
    select productid, price, row_number() over(partition by productID order by price desc) as idx from prices
) T
right join products P on T.productID = P.ID
group by P.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, just the result I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT productId,
        MAX(price) AS highPrice,
        MIN(price) AS lowPrice
FROM prices
GROUP BY productId
```

and if you want the product name in there as well:

```
SELECT name,
        MAX(price) AS highPrice,
        MIN(price) AS lowPrice
FROM products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prices ON ID = ProductID
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: But this doesn't give the user the table of results that he says he's after. Are we sure that he's made a mistake in what he's written?

Comment: I doubt Simdendsjo has made a mistake. i was just showing how you can use the MAX and MIN built in functions to get this out. if you run my second query and replace "name" with "id", you'll get the exact same result set from the question.

Comment: Boy, why did I not see this simple solution.

Comment: If you look at the second line of the required results set it shows the 'highPrice' as 300 and the 'lowPrice' as NULL. Your code won't do that. Whether or not the Rasmus really wants the results set is a separate question (probably he doesn't)

Comment: @Yellowfog, ahhhhh i see what your talking about now

Answer (score 4):

This is for MySQL, but it might work for you too.

```
SELECT
products.id as productId
, MIN(price) as highPrice
, MAX(price) as lowPrice
FROM products
  LEFT JOIN prices ON products.id=prices.productId
GROUP BY products.id
```